# Ngrx waiting for Multiple API calls in effect

Tags: api, rxjs, ngrx, effect

I'm super new about ngrx and I'm trying to develop an effect to dispatch multiple calls to my API to retrive a child list of objects.

Here my code.

```
loadMyChildren$ = createEffect (() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(SomeActions.loadMyChildren),
    switchMap(({parentsObjArr}) => {
            const obsList$: Observable<ChildModel>[] = parentsObjArr.result.map(parentsObj => this.childrenService.loadTimeSeries(parentsObj));
            let childrenArr: ChildModel[] = [];     
            const source$ = zip(obsList$);
            source$.subscribe((res) =>{
                childrenArr = res;
            }, err => { console.log(err); });

            console.log('childrenArr', childrenArr)
            return [
                SomeActions.loadChildrenSuccess({childrenArr}),
                SomeActionsTwo.loadParentsSuccess({parentsObjArr})
            ]
    }),
    catchError((err) => {
        return of(SomeActions.loadMyChildrenFailed)
    })
)
```

Unfortunately my effect seem doesn't wait for my API requests complete on "zip" (I tried also combineLatest and forkJoin) before dispatching the actions on the return array... "console.log" of my objects array is always empty and the store, consequently, does not keep any data.

What I'm wrong?

rxjs 6.6.0
angular 13.2.3

Answer (score 0):

It's not good practise to manualy subscribe inside switchMap.

You are right, your code returns action before your API requests completes, you need to manipultate the stream without subscribing inside.

I would refactor your coude, so source$ is returned in switchMap, but its result is maped to desired ngrx actions with props that you wanted.
It would looked something like that:

```
  switchMap(({parentsObjArr}) => 
     zip(parentsObjArr.result.map(parentsObj => this.childrenService.loadTimeSeries(parentsObj)))
     .pipe(
       map(child => [
           SomeActions.loadChildrenSuccess({child}),
           SomeActionsTwo.loadParentsSuccess({parentsObjArr})
          ]
      )
    )
  )
```